# MouseArea inside SplitView item takes mouse events away from Splitview handle

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I am using qt quick controls 2 `SplitView` and it seems like any `MouseArea` inside the `SplitView`'s item takes mouse events away from the `SplitView` handle. This means that dragging the handle is not possible when the handle is over a component that has a `MouseArea`, e.g. `Button`, inside the `SplitView`'s item.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    SplitView {
        id: splitView
        anchors.fill: parent
        handle: Rectangle {
            id: handle
            implicitWidth: 20
            color: "red"
        }

        Page {
            id: firstPage
            Button {
                id: button
                implicitWidth: 100
                implicitHeight: 50
                text: "button"
            }
        }

        Page {
            id: secondPage
        }
    }
}
```

Normal behaviour:

[image: working gif]

Button blocks mouse events from handle:

[image: not working gif]

I tried setting the z value of `splitView` and `handle` greater than the z value of `firstPage` and `button` but that didn't work.

Comment: You might need to report this one as a bug. I looked, but didn't find an existing report of it. The closest I found was [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-76096).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   Page {
        id: firstPage
        clip: true
        Button {
            id: button
            implicitWidth: 100
            implicitHeight: 50
            text: "button"
        }
    }
```

You have to active clip on page.
I tested on a empty projet it work.:D I suppose the right side of loaded button under handle bar is still active. (if someone know precisely why leave a comment)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the z value of first page and second page to -1 and SplitView to 1

Comment: Still same behaviour unfortunately